# create new variables in class how can i change variable names?

Tags: php, oop

I want to create new variable but name as $class..
For example my $class is:

```
array("veriekle","vericek","sayfala");
```

I want to include there class in my class. (veriekle.class.php,vericek.class.php,etc.). I can this but how can I create new variable.

If "veriekle".class.php called I want to create new variable as name's "veriekle".
This is my class I can include but I can't create new variable.

```
Class Database
{
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        foreach($class as $class)
        {
            require_once("sub/" . $class . ".class.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach($class as $class)` this does not work, you need to have two different variable names here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$$class = new $class();
```

it is called variable variaable and isn't recommended, but there it is

Comment: similar to $$class = new $class(); ??

Comment: @Programmer: exactly. IT is like you'd do `$variekle = new variekle()`

Comment: what maybe? Warning: Missing argument 1 for Database::__construct(), called in C:\AppServ\www\ozetizle\classes\sub\veriekle.class.php on line 12 and defined in C:\AppServ\www\ozetizle\classes\database.class.php on line 4

Comment: @Programmer: yes, there is argument missing.

Comment: @Programmer: you need to call `new Database(array("veriekle","vericek","sayfala"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct($classes)
{
    foreach($classes as $class)
    {
        require_once("sub/" . $class . ".class.php");
    }
}
```